# Spring batch falls under which design pattern

Tags: spring, design-patterns, spring-batch

I was going through the famous GoF - [Gang of Four](https://springframework.guru/gang-of-four-design-patterns/).

I happen to work a lot around Spring-batch framework. So I was wondering which design pattern it falls under.

I think Spring batch should fall under  - [Chain Of Responsibility](https://springframework.guru/gang-of-four-design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility-pattern/)  design pattern where - each layer delegates commands to a chain of processing objects.

Am I correct?

Comment: To be a good framework, it doesn't necessarily need to follow a design pattern. That said, I suppose it has a multi-tiered architecture and different good techniques/patterns are implemented there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Batch does not fall under a given design pattern but it uses several design patterns in its core concepts like:

- Builders: like `FlatFileItemReaderBuilder` and `FlatFileItemWriterBuilder` to build item readers/writers
- Factories: like `JobBuilderFactory` and `StepBuilderFactory` to create jobs and steps
- Chain of responsibility: as in `CompositeItemProcessor`/`CompositeItemWriter` to call a chain of delegate processors/writers in sequence
- Adapters: like `ItemReaderAdapter` and `ItemWriterAdapter` to adapt any object as a reader/writer
- etc

Answer (score -1):

Spring Batch use extensively the Delegate pattern

Comment: Spring Batch uses it but it isn't that pattern. See the accepted answer.